# What is the difference between `el` and `template` in vue component and app?

Tags: vuejs2

A VUE component (and the app itself) have an `el:` and also a `template`.

I want to understand what the difference is, when do I use one and when the other:

If I create a project with Monaca CLI from the minimal VUE-OnsenUI template I see:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  template: '<app></app>',
  components: { App }
});
```

From the very verbose documentation lacking examples, to make a long story short, I gather that the `template` dom element and everything in it will replace the `el` dom element. (The template can only have a single root, right?). For example : If my html is:

```
<html>...
  <body>...
    <replaceThis></replaceThis>...
```

and my vue js says:

```
el: "replace-this", 
template: "<div id='replaced'>hi there</div>"
```

Then I will get :

```
<html>...<body>...<div id='replaced'>hi there</div>...
```

but I can also write:

```
el: "#bla", 
template: "#blu"
```

Then if my html is

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="bla">
       anything inside here including the surrounding div will be replaced 
    </div>
    <template id="blu">
       <span id ="replacing-html">
           when ran in span, it stays mainly in the pan
       </span> 
    </template>
  </body>
</html>
```

then the div with id `bla` will be replaced with the `replacing-html` span elelment that is inside the `template`. (the template tag itself with everything in it will still remain in the emitted html. correct?)

So I need to understand:

1. Is the `template` content replacing the `el` element?
2. Must the `template` only have a single root element directly under it?
3. Am I correct with my first example?
4. Am I correct about the second example?
5. Will the `template` tag with everything in it remain in the emitted html?
6. What happens in the case of the Monaca Vue-OnsenUI example above where the `el` is the same as the template: "app". Isn't this recursive? What is replaced and with what?

Comment: Please don't change your question after you've already accepted an answer to your original question. If you have a new question, create a new post for it.

Comment: I didn't really change it, but rather updated for clarity. And commented on the accepted and correct answer, by elaborating with examples.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[From the documentation on the `el` option:](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#el)

> Provide the Vue instance an existing DOM element to mount on. It can be a CSS selector string or an actual HTMLElement.
>
> After the instance is mounted, the resolved element will be accessible as vm.$el.
>
> If this option is available at instantiation, the instance will immediately enter compilation; otherwise, the user will have to explicitly call vm.$mount() to manually start the compilation.

---

[From the documentation on the `template` option:](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#template)

> A string template to be used as the markup for the Vue instance. The template will replace the mounted element. Any existing markup inside the mounted element will be ignored, unless content distribution slots are present in the template.
>
> If the string starts with # it will be used as a querySelector and use the selected element’s innerHTML as the template string. This allows the use of the common  trick to include templates.

---

In your example, the Vue instance you are defining is registering an `app` component and then using that in its template definition. It is also looking for an existing element in the DOM with an id of `app` to use as it's associated element when mounting.

I think your confusion is coming from the fact that both are using something named "app". They don't have to be named the same thing.

Comment: So this answer in fact answers the following (I modified the question for clairty):    

1. Is the template content replacing the el element?  YES    
2. Must the template only have a single root element directly under it? YES    
3. Am I correct with my first example? YES    
4. Am I correct about the second example? YES    
5. Will the template tag with everything in it remain in the emitted html?  YES

Comment: and 6. 6. What happens in the case of the Monaca Vue-OnsenUI example above where the el is the same as the template: "app". Isn't this recursive?  What is replaced and with what?    Answer: the app element in the code will be replaced by "itself" in the HTML but meanwhile  the component also has js and css that is connected with it within the "scope" of this app. In the case of a navigator or tab or splitter, the code can set a page to show which is in a second component outside app. Further interaction with the navigator/tabs can change the currently shown page.

Comment: @pashute If you want to post your own answer to better address each of the new questions in your post you can. Then I'll delete my post which was addressing the earlier version of your question.

Comment: No, I meant to accept the answer. Seems I forgot to do so. Thank you for setting me on track!